# Is there some function to combine multiple sequences over a function?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, sequence

If I have two sequences

```
(let [v1 '(1 2 3 4)
      v2 '(2 4 6 8)]
  ...)
```

is there some way of combining them through a function to single vector, something like:

```
(combine #(* % %2) [1 2 3 4] [2 4 6 8]) => [2 8 18 32]
```

The "mapping" function would take one argument for each sequence "combined", so calling it with 3 sequences would require a 3-arity function.
If either sequence runs out of elements it should either just stop or repeat the shorter one, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `map` function for this (from `clojure.core`).

`map` takes a function as its first argument, and any number of sequences as its subsequent arguments. It constructs each element of the output by taking an element from each input sequence and applying the function with that collection of elements as arguments, just as you require.

So your example would become:

```
(map * [1 2 3 4] [2 4 6 8])
```